# javascript - Remove seconds from clock script

Tags: javascript, wordpress, datepicker, clock

I would like to make a small modification on this [script](http://temporario.web929.uni5.net/datepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js).

[Demo](http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

It's a datepicker for bootstrap.

Using the demo provided on the website above you'll soon realize what I'm trying to change.

When you select a date, by clicking on a day, I would like it to change automatically to the CLOCK feature, and it would be great if the clock had only hours and minutes, excluding seconds -

I've tried so far:
showSeconds: false but it doesn't works.
Study and trying to adapt a series of things on the javascript file, but no success. I'm not very good at javascript :/

Can someone give me some light on this?

Comment: yeah I'm sorry, I thought that one went to the bottom already... And I thought I could explain it better this time, providing direct link to the script, etc - I'll delete the other one

Answer (score 0):

I am uncertain of how to make the date pick automatically go to the time settings after clicking on a date, but I have been able to modify the files so you can get rid of the seconds.

Instead of pasting all of the code, I made the modifications here: http://jsbin.com/ujuwej/1/edit

Quick rundown of what I did.

I made this call to start the plugin:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm PP',
    pick12HourFormat: true
  });
```

Notice the format has no seconds.

If you take a look at the function:

```
TPGlobal.getTemplate = function(is12Hours)
```

and compare my version to the original, you will notice I simply removed the last cell for each row in the table.  This effectively removed displaying the seconds.

Hope this is what you were looking for!